# camel service discovery got error when local consul client forcibly shutdown

Tags: apache-camel, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I'm using camel as micro service gateway, and consul cluster as service discovery center.

Every camel gateway connect localhost consul client(recommend on production mode) for service discovery.

If I forcibly shutdown the consul client on gateway node, gateway can not get any service info on consul cluster.

Requests are still coming, and all the responses got 500 status code.

I'm curious that consul cluster can tolerate N server failure (2N + 1 servers), but can not handle any client failure.

That's very weird. Does I misunderstand something?

The camel use camel-consul-starter to config consul.

```
cloud:
  consul:
    service-discovery:
      url: "http://localhost:8500"
```

The camel serviceDiscovery component can only connect to one client node.

Should I use virtual IP instead of localhost to connect consul cluster?